# Component Router (AngularJS 1.5) useAsDefault config

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-1.5

I am new to Component Router. I am using it in angular 1.5 and I would like to define a default component in the case a user try to access a route not defined in the config :

I have an app component with this config :

```
$routeConfig: [
   { path: '/...', name: 'Layout', component: 'layout', useAsDefault: true }
]
```

and a layout component with this config

```
$routeConfig: [
    {path: '/', name: 'Home', component: 'home', useAsDefault: true},
    {path: '/user', name: 'User', component: 'user' }
]
```

I can access to the urls *localhost:8080/#/* and *localhost:8080/#/user* but
when I try to access localhost:8080/#/test it doesn't redirect me to the home component although the useAsDefault is set to true (I obtain a blank page...).

Has anyone faced this problem ?